# Why does my project continue to look for an obsolete subfolder?

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I changed the name of a subfolder in my project from "SOs_Forms" to "SOs_Pages"

Now, though, on noticing that several places in my project still referred to the old "SOs_Forms" I changed those to the updated name. But now the project won't compile, saying "*Cannot resolve symbol 'Bla'*" and then offering, through intellisense, to let me add the reference to the old subfolder/namespace.

So now I have both "SOs_Forms" and "SOs_Pages" referenced throughout my project; it seems that either/both are accepted at times, but other times it *must* be SOs_Forms, which no longer exists!

The odd thing about it being, if I acquiesce and allow the "old" subfolder namespace ("SOs_Forms") to be added so that the project will compile, and then right-click the formerly recalcitrant object name and select "Go to Declaration," it pops up "in \SOs_Pages" for both the xaml and the xaml.cs file. IOW, it knows it lives in "SOs_Pages" and yet forces me to add a reference to "SOs_Forms" so that it can be found...weird!

How can I tell the project once and for all that SOs_Forms is gone and is not coming back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a global find and replace you should resolve this issue (I have had to do it a few times).

Firstly before you do anything like this ideally you should have your code source controlled, and checked in so you can easily un-do it. If you don't have a source control system then stop everything and get one, seriously. (but if you can't at least take a copy of your code as it is and place it somewhere safe)

Now go to edit, find and replace, replace in files. Now type in the old namespace, then the new namespace. Then hit the go button.

That should solve it for you.

Comment: Easy enough; I'm still curious, though, about the odd behavior: why would appeasing it with an obsolete subfolder/namespace name work? Anyway, I do use source control of a sort, namely the utility that allows you to right-click a folder and select "Clean, remove source bindings, and zip solution" and WinMerge. I keep my daily or more often backups on a usb stick.